# Unable to unlock domain admin accounts

Tags: active-directory

I am unable to unlock several domain admin accounts across multiple domains. Things I have tried:

1. Checked security logs: there are no failures listed
2. Changed passwords on the accounts
3. Rebooted the DC's

Unlocking the account in ADUC seems to do nothing. As soon as you reopen the user it is already locked out again. The only thing that changes is the badPasswordTime attribute is updated.

I've noticed this behavior across several of our domains with different accounts effected each time. The only solution I've found is to change the login name, however, I would like to find a better solution.

To the best of my knowledge there are no services using the effected accounts.

**EDIT:** Turns out it was a brute force. We started blocking the traffic on our firewall at each site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to unlock account in AD](https://serverfault.com/questions/280115/unable-to-unlock-account-in-ad)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the accounts you are looking at are being brute force attacked. I would turn on failure auditing on your domain controller, and check the logs for failed attempts. If the badPasswordTime attribute is being incremented, something is trying to log into the account with a bad password. Turning on logging for those may also help you find where they are being "attacked" from.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the GPO and failures weren't being audited. I turned them on and the account is being brute forced. Any idea how to find out where it is coming from to block it?

Comment: Check the similar post linked in my comment.